# Best way to go about logging the usage of our app?

Tags: android, logging

I'm currently working on an app for my company that connects to our LED lighting fixtures. We rent out tablets to customers for them to use as they're installing the fixtures. What we'd like to do is be able to keep a log of the commands sent to the fixture.

Would just keeping track of the information in a text file be the best way to go about this? For example: write to the file every time a command is sent. Or is there a library or something that would be a better alternative?

There's probably a library in android itself that I'm missing. It doesn't have to be too complicated just a basic text file.

Update: Well I decided the best way to go about this was to just write my own basic class to take care of this. **https://github.com/trevordavies095/Logger**

This will allow you to write to a simple text file whenever you call `log.write()`. Hope this helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I think Firebase Analytics is what you want!

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/

and

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

> You can use Analytics to log custom events that make sense for your app, like E-Commerce purchases or achievements.

Whenever the user sends a command you can log it in the code and it'll be sent to your Firebase Analytics console.

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

// ...


// Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

You'll have to add Firebase dependencies to your app.

**EDIT:** Posted just a tad later after the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation and your concern about the privacy of your users.

If you are able to get the physical tablets from time to time to read out your textfiles or display statistics inside of the app without syncing the data somewhere that will work, but only in a very small scenario.

Maybe you should think about your apps architecture a bit and implement a model class for your data and serialize those objects or put them in a persistence library like [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

Or you could use [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) and create events, if those tablets have internet.